# A general gstreamer pipeline use xvimagesink to pull rtmp stream with/without audio

Tags: audio, video, gstreamer, pipeline

Assuming that there are 2 kinds of streams, one is only video stream (without audio), the other is video with audio. We know that playbin with a uri can play them all even if we dont know what kind of stream we get, but is there any pipelines that use xvimagesink or nv3dsink (not autovideosink etc.) that can receive both (with or without audio) cause we dont know whether the video stream is with audio or not?

For instance, if the video stream is with audio, we play video with audio, else we play video without audio.

I've tried

```sh
gst-launch-1.0 rtmpsrc location="$RTMP_SRC" ! \
    flvdemux name=demux \
    demux.audio ! queue ! decodebin ! autoaudiosink \
    demux.video ! queue ! decodebin ! autovideosink
```

but if the video is without audio, only one frame would be shown on the screen.

https://github.com/matthew1000/gstreamer-cheat-sheet/blob/master/rtmp.md
This article helps me a lot, but i'm still looking for a excellent general pipeline that works like "playbin" but use xvimagesink or nv3dsink for playing video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may just use video-sink property of playbin:

```
gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=https://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm video-sink=xvimagesink

gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=https://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm video-sink=nv3dsink
```

Comment: Nice to see it helped. If this solved your case, please set this topic as answered.